# Find $\arg\max_b \int_0^\infty \log(1 - b + bx) f(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization, numerical-methods

While I was doing something, I encountered that I need to solve the following problem;

Find $$\arg\max_b \int_0^\infty \log(1 - b + bx) f(x) dx$$ where $0 \leq b \leq 1$ and $f$ is a probability density function with its non-negative support (i.e. $supp(f) \subset [0, \infty)$).

I differentiated the equation (under the Leibniz rule), and I found that I need to find a solution of
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1 -b +bx} f(x) dx = 1.$$

This problem may have some errors as it is originated from my idea, not from a well-written book. Therefore you guys can ignore those errors or just add some assumptions (e.g. $f \in C^\infty$) if necessary.

By the way, I think that the problem does not have a closed-form solution in general, but I am not sure. So my questions are

1. Is there any closed-form solution?
2. If not, how can I approximate or estimate $b$, especially in a numerical way?

Thank you guys for helping me.

Comment: I think the condition should have 0 in the right hand side, not 1

Comment: @uranix well, I need to say that it is 1, not 0. Thanks.